# Missing link on Guidelines for Great Subjective Questions?

Tags: bug, status-completed, broken-link, blog

I was just reading this great old post about [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/), where some interesting guidelines are proposed regarding how to handle Subjective questions properly (really recommended reading btw).

However, when reading the **Guidelines for Great Subjective Questions**, on item No. 5 it reads:

> We like you. We want to believe you. But like Wikipedia itself, **{% raw %}{{citation needed}}{% endraw %}**. And good subjective questions make this clear from the outset: back it up!

Is this "citation needed" a missing or broken link of some sort or is it by design?

Comment: It's supposed to say `[citation-needed]`, formatted in the Wikipedia style, but it looks like some overzealous encoding struck.

Comment: It makes sense, I know it is an old post but a typo in those important guidelines is something relevant IMO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe there was ever a link there. To my recollection, that phrase was formatted using a literal code block like this:

> But like Wikipedia itself, `[citation needed]`.

I'll see if I can find someone to take a look at it.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Although the meaning is not lost, it is a bit confusing to see such strange formatting. Hope my observation is helpful.

Comment: I see that this has been fixed on the Blog Post. I'm going to accept this answer as such. Maybe some mod can consider marking this as status completed if it justifies so.